# ie7 not taking max-height max-width css attributes?

Tags: html, css

I am having a page where i give max-height max-width property to image element. It is working fine in chrome and firefox but not in ie-7.

Comment: Any markup for us to look at?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS max-height not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520710/css-max-height-not-working)

Comment: try `_width:expression(document.body.clientWidth>499?"500px":"auto")` and `_height:expression(this.scrollHeight>499?"500px":"auto")` and you can chack [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAX width working in IE-7 according to Microsoft check the link below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx#positioning

But you have to set appropriate doctype

Comment: As an additional note i was actually working in xslt and the xslt was outputting the html. So i had no idea of how to add the doctype. Did that with xsl:output

Comment: check this link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms530809.aspx

DOCTYPE is important

It bears repeating. If you're having trouble getting this feature to work in IE7, make sure you've started with a strict DOCTYPE, such as:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Strict//EN">

Comment: @CSSGuy What if I'm using HTML5 with <!DOCTYPE html>? Is there no way to have IE7 recognize the max-width and max-height properties then?

Answer (score 1):

Try this css

```
*max-height:400px;
*max-width:400px;
```

like that

Answer (score 0):

```
*+html #div {
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

use this code ... i think its useful for you............

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

refer this link u will get more information about how to control IE stylesheet