# Max-height on border-boxed div with padding is not set

Tags: css

We use the percentage trick on paddings to keep aspect ratio to a div when the user scales his window. Like this:

```
.div {
    background: red;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
}
```

Now we would like to be able to set a maximum height to this div. Because the height of the div is determined by the padding on the div we would need the div to be border-boxed. So far so good. When trying to use a min-height on the div, this works. The max-height on this div however does not work for some reason.

```
.div {
    max-height: 60px;
}
```

I created a fiddle to show you what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/UxuEB/3/.

Tested this on Chrome, FF and IE. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong or why this doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Duplicate question. Doctype is the problem -- you need one. See this article
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520710/css-max-height-not-working

Comment: This doctype is set. Both in my page and in the fiddle, so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The property `max-height` works on the `height` of the element and you want to use it on the `height` and `padding-bottom`.

I think you are confused by the `box-sizing` property that it changes the element height to the overal height including the padding top and bottom (also me). But this is not the case as you will see in the jsFiddle example.

An example:

- The element with content is `100px` in height.
- The `max-height` is set to `50px` (element is now `50px` in height).
- Now we apply the `padding-bottom` of `100px` (more then the height of the element). The padding of `100px` is added to the total height of the element making it `150px`.

JsFiddle example: [clicky](http://jsfiddle.net/wm856/)

Comment: According to w3 http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing, when border-box is set the height should be calculated by substracting the border-width and paddings from the height. The min-height does work as I would expect, why doesn't the max-height work? What's the difference?

Comment: I think I get it now. Read the specification some more. Exactly as you said, the box-sizing property does not change the element height to the overal height. In the usual cases it does seem to work like that but in this case it doesn't. The height is substracted usually by the padding and border but now the height is 0 and can't become less than 0 so the padding keeps defining the height of this div. This also is the reason min-height does work, it makes the total height higher than 0 instead of less. 
Thanks for your explanation. Any ideas on how to work around my problem?

Comment: Well I discussed it with co-workers and we coudn't find a real answer for your case because the percentages in the padding makes it difficult, sorry. About the min-height; the one in your example worked because the padding (1%) was less then the min-height of the element.

Answer (score 21):

I realize this answer comes incredibly late to the party but I was trying to solve this exact same thing today and this question is the first result in Google. I ended up solving it with the below code so hopefully that will help someone out in the future.

First, add an extra inner div:

```
<div class="control control-max-height">
  <div class="control-max-height-inner">
    Max-height
  </div>
</div>
```

And set the padding on that while hiding the overflow on the outer div:

```
.control {
    background: red;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.control-max-height {
    max-height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.control-max-height-inner {
    padding-bottom: 20%;
}
```

This obviously assumes you're fine with hiding part of the inner element when it overflows. In my case that wasn't a problem because the inner element is just an empty link element to make the whole thing clickable and the outer element just has a centered background image and a border set.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UxuEB/7/

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` was my missing piece. Thanks!

Comment: Gracias for your work! Mate...

Answer (score 8):

Extending from Mike's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31272053/2553600), the same can be achieved with a single DOM element & a pseudo element, eg.

html:

```
<div class="le-div"></div>
```

css:

```
div.le-div {
  max-height: 200px;
  /*  only necessary if applying any styles to the pseudo element
     other than padding:

     overflow: hidden;
  */

}

div.le-div::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer, tried it and worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: Yes, the padding is the main problem.

Comment: I like to use this trick with margin instead of padding, so that it can collapse with margins of content elements.

Answer (score 3):

Min-height property defines the height when height is solely dependent on padding only but max-height does not.

Not sure why but now in 2020, min and max css units does nice job as we need.

```
.classthatshoulddefineheight {
   padding-bottom: min(20%, 60px); 
}
```

So when 20% becomes greater than 60px then it will be limited to 60px (minimum of them).

Answer (score 0):

The limitation to Mike's answer (and this Brad's answer - although Brad's technique can be incorporated to reduce the number of levels of containers) is that it requires overflow: hidden - which in my use-case (and in many others) a significant limitation.

I've reworked his example to work without overflow: hidden; using an additional level and absolute positioning.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ksh56cr/2/

The trick is to add another container inside the inner box, make it absolute positioned and then add the max-height to that container as well:

```
.inner-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 120px;
}
```

As long as your fine with having some additional DOM-elements, this should work in all scenarios for more or less all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: flow-root;` on the parent container.