# CSS: padding-bottom and max-height on a div do not work well together

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a div that has extra space below its contents.

I don't know the height of the div a priori, but I set `max-height`, so it shouldn't go beyond that. However, when I add space (using `paddding-bottom`) the div expands in height beyond max-height.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4c704yx/2/)

**Question:** How can I add the space on the bottom without increasing height?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31272053/1913115) but it requires nesting divs, and I can't do that because I'm using bootstrap and that would require rewriting compiled CSS (things like `.dropdown>ul>li`).

Comment: max-height:100px + padding-bottom:200px ??? what are you trying to do ? because if you reset box-sizing, then there is something that's gonna break ... oups forgot to mention also overflow-y:auto; :) ??

Comment: Padding is the inside of the div. If you want space outside the div to expand you want `margin-bottom: 100px;`

Comment: i'm trying to implement virtual scrolling, so i need to pad the bottom `<li>` to simulate proper height. overflow-y:auto to enable scrolling (e.g. if i have 200 items)

Comment: margin-bottom doesn't do anything here - try it in my jsfiddle

Comment: ?? it works fine  if you remove the padding : https://jsfiddle.net/g4c704yx/3/

Comment: @GCyrillus I know. But I just said I'm trying to implement virtual scrolling. so I can't load 200 (or 2000) elements all at once, I simply want to make the div as tall as it would be if all 2000 elements were loaded and when user scrolls, it'll fill them in.

Comment: then add the padding on the last-child, not the container itself :) https://jsfiddle.net/g4c704yx/4/

Comment: I guess that's an option, I'll just do it dynamically in a JS function. Was hoping to get away with computed properties (i'm using Vue.JS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a pseudo and a negative `margin` if you want things treated from ul and not its `:last-child`: https://jsfiddle.net/g4c704yx/9/

```css
ul.dropdown-menu{
  border:1px #ccc solid;
  width:200px;
  max-height:100px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  }
 ul.dropdown-menu:before {/* using :before has its purpose, it will disseaper once the content will reach 200em height meaning content has an equal top negative margin, :after will always add 200em or will be swallowed if a negative margin is applied at content's bottom */
   content:'';
   display:block;
  padding-top:200em;/* average 200 lines ? */
}
ul.dropdown-menu li:first-child {  /* this margin-top has its purpose */
margin-top:-200em; /* climb back up those 200 empty lines made of padding                        and i'm gonne pull up all my folowing siblings, i'm a leader, i'm a ladder !*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

200em is 200lines of 1em line-height and no padding ..

Comment: I actually simplified your answer a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/g4c704yx/11/ but it works. thanks!

Comment: @andrei great! that means you totally got it and did not copy/paste ... just alike a *virtual* :last-child

Comment: ...i did copy/paste your answer, that's why i marked it as _the answer_, i just removed the margin-top bit.

Comment: @andrei  i meant you understood it , sometimes answser are accepted and used. a few days later the question comes up again, a little different because how it worked was not fullly understood :)

Comment: ah, gotcha. i thought you were being sarcastic :)) they should really add emoticons here to convey mood. lol.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is to set a `margin-bottom` on the final element in the list:

```
.dropdown-menu li:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}
```

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/sgpb4yjc/2/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:  https://jsfiddle.net/g4c704yx/8/

Try to add padding to the last li element.

```
li:last-child {
  padding-bottom:300px;
}
```

and remove from ul your paddings