# preventing DIV height going over a certain value

Tags: html, css

I have a long text wrapped in a `DIV` witch is inside a `TD`.
The `TD` width is fixed to `90px` and the DIV `max-height: 60px`.
In Chrome and FireFox it is ok, it is 60px by 90px with a vertical scroll bar, but in Internet explorer the DIV height it's adjusted to the text length with no scroll bar.

I want that the height of div to be able to adjust to a maximum of 60px and have a scroll bar if the contents is larger. In Chrome, FireFox and Internet Explorer 11.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .medium {
            width:90px;
            max-width:90px;
            overflow: auto;
            word-break: break-all;
        }
        div.scrollable {
            overflow:auto;
            max-height:60px; /* 3 lines maximum */
            height:60px;
            text-align:left;
            white-space: pre-wrap; /* preserve the text formatting */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="medium">
                <div class="scrollable">In my design I've multiple Div that contain some text and one of them is a lot bigger that the height of a normal screen resolution. In my design I've multiple Div that contain some text and one of them is a lot bigger that the height of a normal screen resolution.In my design I've multiple Div that contain some text and one of them is a lot bigger that the height of a normal screen resolution.In my design I've multiple Div that contain some text and one of them is a lot bigger that the height of a normal screen resolution.</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which IE Version are you looking at ??

Comment: I'm using IE11, and works fine. Look here http://jsfiddle.net/Cew3L/

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the issue ?? - @Ionut

Comment: Are you using the DOCTYPE please see the link it may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520710/css-max-height-not-working

Comment: @NathanLee : I think I am going crazy, now it is working fine. I do not know why. I am sorry for wasting your time, guys